# What character was pressed, with onkeydown (and not onkeypress)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-events

I need to know **what character** is pressed during a `onkeydown` event.

- This answer looks simple...

  `window.onkeydown = function (e) {
        console.log(e.key);
        e.preventDefault();  // I need this for something else
    }`

  .. but it does not work for Chrome : `undefined`.
- This :

  `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)`

  does not work neither  because it does not make difference between `a` and `A`, `-` and `6` (with my french keyboard layout, but it would be something else with another layout).

**How to know what character is pressed during a `onkeydown` event ?**
Is there a solution with jQuery ?

---

**Important note** : the answer could be : *"Dont't do that, use `onkeypress` instead"*.
This would not work for my purpose, because, on Chrome, when `onkeypress` is called, it is **too late** for preventing default browser's behaviour with `e.preventDefault()`.   So I really need to use `onkeydown`.

**Importante note 2** : what I want to achieve **at the end** is to be able (during `onkeydown`) to know if the key `+`  (or `=`, as it is on the same key)   has been pressed.
Using `keyCode` is not easy because `+`can be :

```
FF WIN     CHROME WIN     IE WIN      FF MAC     SAFARI MAC     
61          187           187          173           189 !! (= the key - on CHROME WIN !!)
```

or `1O7` with US layout, etc. I'm sure it has lots of differents values with other keyboard layouts.

Comment: The `keydown` event doesn't tell you which _character_ was pressed, it tells you which _key._ Anyway, you're looking for `e.which`.

Comment: @nnnnnn, how to find then if the `+` key has been pressed, crossbrowser, cross OS, and cross keyboard layout ? (That's not easy, see the table at the end of my question)

Comment: There are two `+` keys on my keyboard, one that is the same key as `=` (press shift for `+` - and you can test for shift in your event handler), and one in the numeric keypad. Are you trying to test both?

Comment: [event.charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.charCode) and [event.which docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.which)

Comment: @nnnnnn @Blazemonger No, `event.which` doesn't solve the problem at all : it can be 61 (FF), 187 (Chrome), 173 (FF Mac), etc. and lots of other values on other browsers or keyboard layout.... So this won't help me to locate `+`.

Comment: @Blazemonger the doc that you linked says `charCode is never set in the keydown and keyup events.`

Comment: What is the default browser behaviour that you're trying to prevent?

Comment: Well, it sounds to me like you've answered your own question. "I need to know what character is pressed during a onkeydown event" -- the answer is that *no* character is generated by `onkeydown`. You can't get the *character* without a full keypress, so you can't use `onkeydown`. The problem is (probably) that a key *combination* might possibly produce a different character from a single key press.

Comment: @nnnnnn : CTRL + PLUS 's zooming

Comment: But why bother when the user can still zoom via the menu or with CTRL + mousewheel?

Comment: @nnnnnn because it is needed for my purpose... But anyway the question would still be true for another key that `+`.